# C# Synchronization Error - CreateThread fail?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

Recently, I received an email which ask me to help about some issue. [The mail was not a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (It didn't have any code, but just one stack trace...), but after some thought and searching, I could assume it's because of synchronization issue. He probably do `queue.Enqueue();` without locking, so I wrote "you should do `lock`!" in response.

Then, I thought it's good to show him a small example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

static class Program
{
    private static Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread[] thrds = new Thread[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //thrds[i] = new Thread(do_safe);
            thrds[i] = new Thread(do_unsafe); // <--
            thrds[i].Start(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            thrds[i].Join();
        }

        foreach (int i in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    private static void do_safe(object k)
    {
        int val = (int)k;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // do something
        {
            val += i;
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }

        lock (q)
            q.Enqueue(val); // with locking
    }
    private static void do_unsafe(object k)
    {
        int val = (int)k;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // do something
        {
            val += i;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        q.Enqueue(val); // without locking
    }
}
```

I tested it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/zOSuMl), and as I expected, the program crashes with `do_unsafe` and works well with `do_safe`.

However, I found that the crash message was strange soon.

```
ves_icall_System_Threading_Thread_Thread_internal: CreateThread error 0x0
Unhandled Exception: System.SystemException: Thread creation failed.
  at System.Threading.Thread.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.Start (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.SystemException: Thread creation failed.
  at System.Threading.Thread.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.Start (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Since synchronization issue occurs with `q.Enqueue`, I expected some exception will be thrown inside it. (And actually, the mail says like this.)

But crash message says thread creation was failed. I know thread synchronization issue can make **any** buggy issues, (this case may be a good practice >o<) but I cannot understand why thread creation is associated with this synchronization issue.

Could you give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: Does this error produce everytime ?

Comment: @dotnetstep Yes. Try it yourself - Go [live example](http://ideone.com/zOSuMl), and fork. I guess this happens in Mono, because the mail says some exception was thrown in `Enqueue` in Microsoft CLR.

Comment: Could this be a limit on ideone? The CreateThread error does not happen if I run the sample locally.

Comment: Hm, could you tell me your local environment? I hope I can test in the same environment with ideone, but I don't know its environment >o<

Comment: The same CreateThread error happens with the do_safe method in ideone too. http://ideone.com/oXJmUd  Note. Change the Thread.Sleep(0) to Thread.Sleep(1) like it is in do_unsafe

Comment: The CreateThread error is specific to ideone. If you try it locally on your machine, you will see that it does crash at the do_unsafe method q.Enqueue call because of synchronization issue.

Comment: I'm facing this issue on Fedora 17. The strange fact is that restarting the service sometimes fixes the issue.